# Radio button value not correct in IE after second click.. working in other browsers

Tags: javascript, image, internet-explorer, radio-button

I am using some code to display radio buttons as images:

HTML:

```
<div id="skin_1" title="Walk">
    <input type="radio" name="travel_mode" id="mode_walking" value="WALKING" /><br>
    Walk
</div>

<div id="skin_2" title="Drive">
    <input type="radio" name="travel_mode" id="mode_driving" value="DRIVING" /><br>
    Drive
</div>

<div id="skin_3" title="Bike">
    <input type="radio" name="travel_mode" id="mode_bicycle" value="BICYCLING" /><br>
    Bike
</div>

<div id="skin_4" title="Transit">
<input type="radio" name="travel_mode" id="mode_transit" value="TRANSIT" /><br>
 Transit
</div>

<div>
  <a href="#" onClick="testMe();">What mode is selected?</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $('input:radio').hide().each(function () {
        var label = $("label[for=" + '"' + this.id + '"' + "]").text();
        $('<a ' + (label != '' ? 'title=" ' + label + ' "' : '') + ' class="radio-fx ' + this.name + '"><span class="radio' + (this.checked ? ' radio-checked' : '') + '"></span></a>').insertAfter(this);
    });
    $('.radio-fx').on('click', function (e) {
        $("input[name=travel_mode]").removeAttr("checked"); // add this line
        $check = $(this).prev('input:radio');
        var unique = '.' + this.className.split(' ')[1] + ' span';
        $(unique).attr('class', 'radio');
        $(this).find('span').attr('class', 'radio-checked');
        this.blur();  
        this.focus(); 
        $check.attr('checked', true);
        getDirections();
    }).on('keydown', function (e) {
        if ((e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which) == 32) {
            $(this).trigger('click');
        }
    });
});
```

This code works fine in all browsers except IE. In IE, after the second click of a radio button the value is "undefined".

I tried using:

```
this.blur();  
this.focus();
```

as per other suggestions but that did not work.

How can I fix this to work in IE also?

[Here is the fiddle](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NRqqKg)

Comment: use prop instead of attr

Comment: Thanks! This works in IE! Please make this the answer. What makes this work?

Comment: actually you are just setting the attribute of radio button in html that will just change the layout but many browser works on property and state of tags radio button is one of them you can check this when you inspect the code and change the state of radio button it will not append anyting in attribute instead it changes the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**use prop instead of attr**

```
   $(function () {
        $('input:radio').hide().each(function () {
            var label = $("label[for=" + '"' + this.id + '"' + "]").text();
            $('<a ' + (label != '' ? 'title=" ' + label + ' "' : '') + ' class="radio-fx ' + this.name + '"><span class="radio' + (this.checked ? ' radio-checked' : '') + '"></span></a>').insertAfter(this);
        });
        $('.radio-fx').on('click', function (e) {
            $("input[name=travel_mode]").prop('checked', false);; // add this line
            $check = $(this).prev('input:radio');
            var unique = '.' + this.className.split(' ')[1] + ' span';
            $(unique).attr('class', 'radio');
            $(this).find('span').attr('class', 'radio-checked');
            this.blur();  
            this.focus(); 
            $check.prop('checked', true);
            getDirections();
        }).on('keydown', function (e) {
            if ((e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which) == 32) {
                $(this).trigger('click');
            }
        });
    });
```